# UE4 - Detect Compute Shader Completion

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently trying to make a plugin for Unreal that involves a compute shader. Currently, my shader runs, and I can access the memory block that it writes to, but I can't get to it at the right time. Either my array isn't fully formed, or I've come too late and all my data is (seemingly) gone. I don't expect there to be a `BlockUntilShaderIsDonePlease` function, but *anything* to go on to grab my data when everything's been filled out would be greatly appreciated.

Currently, I'm trying to loop until I extract the length value I expect from my shader code

```
//This is at the bottom of my usf function
InterlockedExchange(OutputArray[0], OutputArray.IncrementCounter(), Count);
```

Not only does this not work, but it seems like a bad way to go about it.

I've spent the last month scratching away at this, any help from someone who knows what they're talking about would be huge for me. Thanks